# How to place tabs of TabBar in middle and upon clicking next tab, it starts shifting to left?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Mock I am trying to implement:

[image]

Then when starting clicking the next tab i.e 2 it shows 3rd tab (named 3) and 1st tab moves to left. Till eventually to far left slide of the screen.

Mock:

[image]

Finally, when clicked further it shows three dots to left also. FYI clicking on dots does nothing its a representation of showing that more that is there.

Now following is my code.

```
class TabbedAppBarSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: choices.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white, // status bar color
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            title: TimerPage(),
            bottom: TabBar(
              // isScrollable: true,
              indicatorColor:Colors.red,
              unselectedLabelColor:Colors.grey,
              labelColor: Colors.red,
              tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
                return Tab(
                  text: choice.title,

                  // icon: Icon(choice.icon),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: '1'),
  const Choice(title: '2'),
  const Choice(title: '...'),

]; // above is a mock array which eventually will be coming from API call
```

Thanks and bear my coding I am new to flutter.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Need your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

Use TabController to animate to next tab and use PreferredSize to control positon of tabbar

code snippet

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(20.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 200.0),
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  void _toggleTab() {
    _tabIndex = _tabController.index + 1;
    _tabController.animateTo(_tabIndex);
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Tabs Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _tabIndex = 0;

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  void _toggleTab() {
    _tabIndex = _tabController.index + 1;
    _tabController.animateTo(_tabIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 20,
        child: new Row(
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _toggleTab();
              },
              child: Text(
                'Next >',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(20.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 200.0),
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('Hello 1'),
                  subtitle: Text('Click on Next Button to go to Tab 2.'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('Hello 2'),
                  subtitle: Text('Click on Next Button to go to Tab 3'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('Hello 3'),
                  subtitle: Text('The End'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```